# Newtonsoft Json JsonSerializationException with simple string

Tags: json.net, converters, built-in

My datasource creates the JSON representing an array of integers as "1,2,3,4,5". I can't do anything about this (Like changing it to [1,2,3,4,5]), it is an enterprise CMS that we have to just deal with.

I'm trying to read up on how the newtonsoft ToObject method handles the following code:

```
JValue theValue = new JValue("1,2,3") 
List<int> x = theValue.ToObject<List<int>>();
```

I get a Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException. Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String].  I understand this fully, but I'd like to know if the Newtonsoft JSON libraries have a built in way to convert from a comma delimited string to a List.

I'd like to think there's a better way than trying to check if the variable is a comma delimited list or not and then converting it to a List<> manually, or maybe a JArray, but I've been wrong before !

EDIT

**I wanted to share my solution:**

```
dynamic theValue = new JValue("1,2,3,4"); /// This is just passed in, i'm not doing this on purpose. Its to demo.

if (info.PropertyType == typeof (List<int>))
{
    if (info.CanWrite)
    {
        if (theValue.GetType() == typeof (JValue) && theValue.Value is string)
        {
            theValue = JArray.Parse("[" + theValue.Value + "]");
        }

        info.SetValue(this, theValue.ToObject<List<int>>());
   }
} else {
// do other things
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three problems from what I can see:

1. You should be using `JArray` not `JValue`. You are intending this to be an array of things, so you need to use the equivalent class in Newtonsoft to represent an array. (A `JValue`, as best I can tell, represents a simple type--e.g. `string`, `number`, `Date`, etc.)
2. You should use the `Parse` method versus using the constructor. `Parse` will read the content of the string as an array, however...
3. ...in order for it to do that, you will need to surround the data that you get with the square brackets or JArray can't correctly the parse the data. There is no need to fiddle with the CMS; just do a string concat before you parse.

e.g.

```
JArray theValue = JArray.Parse("[" + "1,2,3" + "]");
```

Comment: This did solve the problem.  I believe a slight string manipulation is an acceptable solution, especially when I know the type I'm expecting is a comma delimited list of integers, and the type I want is a List<int>.  Also, FYI the JValue is what Newtonsoft provides me when it tries to deserialize the "1,2,3,4,5". I simply wrote the code out to show you my problem.  Thanks for a quick workaround!